# How to call useNavigate inside useEffect? - For bottom navigation in Ant Design - Mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, antd, antd-mobile

I am new to React. I am making an app using AntD-mobile. For Bottom navigation, I am making use of the [tabBar Component in AntD-mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/components/tab-bar). I was not sure how to use `Link` for routing with TabBar and after a lot of failed attempts, came upon `useNavigate`.

```
const [navLink, setNavLink] = React.useState("/");
const navigate = useNavigate();
const redirect = useCallback(() => navigate(navLink, {replace: true}), [navigate]);
```

I want to redirect to whichever tab is clicked upon, for that, I used State, TabBar's onChange changes the state first and calls redirect. But for some reason, the previous state is loaded. If I am on state 1 and click 2, it stays on 1, When I click 4, it goes to 2 and so on. So probably, the redirect is loading ahead of state change. -

```
<TabBar onChange={(key)=>{setNavLink(key); redirect();}}>
      {tabs.map(item => (
            <TabBar.Item key={item.key} icon={item.icon} title={item.title}>
            </TabBar.Item>
      ))}
</TabBar>
```

To solve, this I tried using `useEffect()`, wherein I change only the state in TabBar's onChange and call redirect inside useEffect. But this doesn't work. redirect is not working.

```
useEffect(() => {
        redirect()
    }, [navLink]);
```

What am I doing wrong? How to set bottom navigation in the tabBar?

Comment: You did not provide any input for `navLink` variable.

Comment: @SMAKSS, where? I didn't get the comment.. I initialized `navLink` with "/" and whenever the user clicks on any tab, its "key" which is the same as the route I want to specify is set using `setNavLink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The original code didn't work because both `setNavLink(key);` *and* `redirect();` happen in the same render cycle. When `redirect` is called the enqueued state update hasn't been processed yet, so it's still the previous state's value.

```
onChange={(key) => {
  setNavLink(key); // <-- enqueued state update
  redirect();      // <-- navLink state not updated yet!
}}
```

## Solutions

The `redirect` function is missing a dependency, adding `navLink` to the dependency array will re-enclose the updated `navLink` state value. `useCallback(() => navigate(navLink, {replace: true}), [navigate]);` only computes/recomputes the callback on the initial render or when the dependencies update.

```
const redirect = useCallback(
  () => navigate(navLink, { replace: true }),
  [navigate, navLink]
);

useEffect(() => {
  redirect()
}, [redirect]);
```

...

```
onChange={setNavLink}
```

You can pass the `navLink` state in as an argument.

```
const redirect = useCallback(
  (navLink) => navigate(navLink, { replace: true }),
  [navigate]
);

useEffect(() => {
  redirect(navLink);
}, [navLink, redirect]);
```

...

```
onChange={setNavLink}
```

Or you can just use `navigate` directly in the `useEffect` when the `navLink` state updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  navigate(navLink, { replace: true });
}, [navLink]);
```

...

```
onChange={setNavLink}
```

Or just navigate directly in the `onChange` handler.

```
<TabBar onChange={(navLink) => navigate(navLink, { replace: true })}>
  {tabs.map(item => (
    <TabBar.Item
      key={item.key}
      icon={item.icon}
      title={item.title}
    />
  ))}
</TabBar>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.
Why didn't my code work? redirect had a callback that used a state - `navLink`. Whenever navLink changes, shouldn't everything which uses it reload?

Comment: @ParthKapadia The original code didn't work because both `setNavLink(key);` *and* `redirect();` happen in the same render cycle. When `redirect` is called the enqueued state update hasn't been processed yet, so it's still the previous state's value.